# Use android support v7 library resources in my library

Tags: android, android-library, android-support-library

I want use android support v7 library's resource in my own library, i set

```
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

but when project build in *gen* folder not generating `android.support.appcompat.R.java` and i can't use resources. When i set `android.library=false` all build ok, file generating. but use this jar in another app project i can't:

```
[2013-11-03 13:49:23 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
[2013-11-03 13:49:23 - MediaKuzbass] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$anim;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the support-v7 lib twice on your project path, change that. Most likely the project you want to build and the different libraries you are using use different folders for the same appcompat lib.

Answer (score 0):

Set the same apptheme to both manifest .

**Bad exemple :**

Your lib :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeChildOfAppCompat" >
```

Your app :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

You'll get the error.

**Solution:**

Your lib :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeChildOfAppCompat" >
```

Your app :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeChildOfAppCompat" >
```